# How to replace string or url containing special character(&) with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

It seems that the  character & in url is creating problem for me.
I have a file called *newurl.txt*, where a new url is updated after every 15 minutes, the url inside the file is something like this

```
url/edu/playlist.m3u8?st=newcode1&e=newcode2
```

I have another file called *replaceoldurl.txt*, where old url need to replace from the file *newurl.txt*

My command is:

```
cat /root/newurl.txt | xargs -I '{}' sed -r -- 's!url[^"[:space:]]+!{}!g' /root/replaceoldurl.txt
```

This command does work, but it leaves the old url beside the new one.
which looks something like this after replacement.

```
url/edu/playlist.m3u8?st=oldcode1url/edu/playlist.m3u8?st=oldcode1&e=oldcode2e=newcode2
```

To me the `&` character seems to make the problem, because it leaves the old url instead of character `&`. Though I tried to escape the character `&`, but still doesn't work. No idea, how to make it work. Searched many questions here, but none of the answered specifically refers to my problems.

Comment: You have to escape the `&`s in the replacing portion. What I don't understand is what you're trying to do. Seems that you're trying to just copy one line of one file to another by using a strange setup of sed and xargs.

Comment: looked like an interesting question, but can't help as am not clear on the ask here. e.g., what are the original contents of replaceoldurl.txt? will it always contain just one line which would be the old url?

Comment: @sidyll I can't do any change in the replace part, because I'm getting replacement part from argument. Or you meant something else?

Comment: @ketan there are some random lines of codes in replaceoldurl.txt and in between is the url which codes, which needs to be replaced every hour. For security reasons I had used oldcode1 and oldcode2, but they look something like this st=IdzyvvtvNq1NBuCkRUJYkQ&e=1451790485

Comment: @user2201239 So there is exactly one URL in each file? The file 'replaceoldurl.txt' can have additional lines that do not contain URLs but 'newurl.txt' has only one line with the new URL, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To me the & character seems to make the problem, because it leaves the
> old url instead of character &. Though I tried to escape the character
> &, but still doesn't work. No idea, how to make it work. Searched many
> questions here, but none of the answered specifically refers to my
> problems.

That's correct, '&' is a special character. For reference here is a snipper from sed's manual that explains the behaviour of '&'.

> s/regexp/replacement/
>
> Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space. If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement. The replacement  may  contain  the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the  special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

How did you escape '&'?

You can try to modify your cat/sed command:

```
cat newurl.txt | sed 's/\&/\\\\&/g' | xargs  -I {} sed -r -- 's!url[^"[:space:]]+!{}!g' oldurl.txt
```

Here you have some explanation why you need to do `\\\\&`:

```
$ cat newurl.txt 
url/edu/playlist.m3u8?st=newcode1&e=newcode2

$ cat newurl.txt | sed 's/\&/\\&/g' 
url/edu/playlist.m3u8?st=newcode1\&e=newcode2

$ cat newurl.txt | sed 's/\&/\\&/g' | xargs  -I {} echo {}
url/edu/playlist.m3u8?st=newcode1&e=newcode2

$ cat newurl.txt | sed 's/\&/\\\\&/g' | xargs  -I {} echo {}
url/edu/playlist.m3u8?st=newcode1\&e=newcode2
```

If you want to do that change inline, just pass '-i' option to sed, like so:

```
$ cat newurl.txt | sed 's/\&/\\\\&/g' | xargs  -I {} sed -r -i -- 's!url[^"[:space:]]+!{}!g' oldurl.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped and the explanation made everything clear.

Comment: Though there is 1 small problem in it. I had used -r with sed in the above code, so that I can see in the command line, but I usually use -i to replace it actually in the file, but with -i its not replacing for some reason.

Comment: You can just use both -i and -r. Is there any issue with that? I've edited my answer and updated with a command to do in-line change.

Comment: Its my silliness that I tried -ir and didn't work, but didn't try them separately, which I tried after reading your comments and it worked, I don't what difference does it make to write them together or separately. Anyways, everything working now and once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` is a special character. In `s///` command the `&` on the right-hand side is replaced by the entire expression matched on the left-hand side. So you need to escape it: `\&`

The possible solution is:

```
cat /root/newurl.txt | \
sed 's/\&/\\\\&/g'  |  \
xargs -I '{}' sed -r -- 's!url.+!{}!g' /root/replaceoldurl.txt
```

You need to use `\\\\&` to get `\&` on the output of `xargs`. If you want to use `-i` option, you shouldn't replace `-r` with it:

```
cat /root/newurl.txt | \
sed 's/\&/\\\\&/g'  |  \
xargs -I '{}' sed -ri -- 's!url.+!{}!g' /root/replaceoldurl.txt
```

Comment: That correct and its working with your solution, but for some reason when I change the sed argument to -i, then it doesn't replace the actual file.

Comment: You should explain *why* `&` is a special character.

Answer (score 0):

You have been presented with solutions that utilize xargs, e.g.

```
cat newurl.txt | sed 's/\&/\\\\&/g' | xargs  -I {} sed -r -- 's!url[^"[:space:]]+!{}!g' oldurl.txt
```

I see from your comments that you want to use the `-i` (in situ) option. You do not have to replace `-r` with `-i`; you can use both like

```
...| xargs  -I {} sed -ri -- 's!url[^"[:space:]]+!{}!g' oldurl.txt
```

Alternatively, you can lose the `-r` option and escape the `+` quantifier

```
... | xargs  -I {} sed -i -- 's!url[^"[:space:]]\+!{}!g' oldurl.txt
```

This solution will work if both files contain *one* URL *each*.

But does it have to be a sed only solution? If not, I would probably solve such a problem with a simple Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read URL;do
    sed -i "\!${URL%?st=*}! {s!.*!${URL//&/\\&}!}" oldurl.txt
done < newurl.txt
```

This will also handle files with multiple URLs, e. g.,

```
$ cat oldurl.txt
Some random
url/edu/playlist3.m3u8?st=oldcode31&e=oldcode32
lines
url/edu/playlist2.m3u8?st=oldcode21&e=oldcode22

url/edu/playlist1.m3u8?st=oldcode11&e=oldcode12
of code
$ cat newurl.txt
url/edu/playlist1.m3u8?st=newcode11&e=newcode12
url/edu/playlist2.m3u8?st=newcode21&e=newcode22
url/edu/playlist3.m3u8?st=newcode31&e=newcode32
```

The resulting oldurl.txt file:

```
$ cat oldurl.txt
Some random
url/edu/playlist3.m3u8?st=newcode31&e=newcode32
lines
url/edu/playlist2.m3u8?st=newcode21&e=newcode22

url/edu/playlist1.m3u8?st=newcode11&e=newcode12
of code
```

Comment: thanks for the while loop solution, but it doesn't really match my needs, as I need to update each individual file separately, but the while loop solution looks great and might help some people looking for similar situation.